# SQL Server View in Dynamics 365 On Premise

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365

I have created a custom T-SQL View in SQL Server against a Dynamics 365 (version 9.2) On Premise Database. Is there anyway I can expose that view to the Dynamics solution so that I can use the out of the box charts?

Comment: Keep in mind that "Modifying tables, stored procedures, or views in the database is not supported. Adding tables, stored procedures, or views to the database is also not supported because of referential integrity or upgrade issues. " [ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328350.aspx#Unsupported]. Essentially, everything you add to the database other than indexes might be erased during any upgrade to the organization.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, those charts are linked to FetchXML queries.

[MS CRM Chart Editor and XML Overview - Fetchcollection](https://crmchartguy.com/ms-crm-chart-editor-and-xml-overview/)

> The fetch collection is where the data is retrieved and aggregated.

I would suggest either:

1. Create a FetchXML chart compatible equivilant of your sql view if possible.
2. Use PowerBi - that is a much richer reporting tool, you can then embed that chart within CRM. For example; [Dynamics 365: Adding Microsoft Power BI Visualization to System Dashboard through IFrame](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/227389).
3. Create [SSRS reports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328097.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, so if I use any of those two options, do they have functionality like pivot, finding the difference between dates, where I can use the results to plug to the visualization? The reason I'm not using OOTB charts is because the views are based on advanced find, which doesn't have any aggregate functionality.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to achieve that in FetchXML - it has the same basic feature as OOTB charts. I think you will want to use PowerBI, its a dedicated reporting tool. Option 3; SSRS reports.

Comment: So with PowerBI, if I pull using custom views from CRM, does PowerBI have arithmetic/aggregate/pivot functionality so that I can manipulate the data into a form I'd like to present on the charts? For example with SSRS I had limited functionality using VB scripts on the forms themselves. I'd like to retrieve the data, then manipulate it again before plotting it to a visualization.

Comment: Generally speaking [yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guided-learning/) though I would recommend further research.